# Run Spring Boot with Eclipse Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm trying to start Spring Boot with Eclipse Tomcat, but it fails.

I'm using Eclipse with following plugins

- BuildShip Gradle Integration 2.0
- Spring Tools 3 Add-On 3.9.6 RELEASE

and I created my project with Spring Boot

- Type: gradle (BuildShip 2.x)
- Packaging: War
- Java Version: 8
- Language: Java

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'heykj.web'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    //providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1"
}
```

This is my application class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PlusFApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlusFApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PlusFApplication.class);
    }

}
```

My project facets:

[image: My project facets]

I don't understand why this does not work. I think Eclipse Tomcat can't find the  Main Class. I added servlet-api but it doesn't work.
How can I solve it?

Sorry! there was some typo and I missed my situation.
First, I know that Spring Boot embedded Tomcat.
Second, I want to start with Eclipse Tomcat, not Spring Boot embedded Tomcat.
thanks!

11/09/2018
I tried this but still fail..
build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }

    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'

}
```

Still Tomcat can't find my Application Class.
I think need to add servlet-class into web.xml.

11/09/2018 - 2
build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        //compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
}
```

totally exclude spring-boot-start-tomcat and i added servleet-api.
now they give me the error.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2018-11-09 17:10:34.138  INFO 8712 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-E0BBPVE with PID 8712 (C:\Users\knowch\eclipse-workspace\demo\bin\main started by knowch in C:\Users\knowch\eclipse-workspace\demo)
2018-11-09 17:10:34.142  INFO 8712 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-09 17:10:34.796  WARN 8712 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2018-11-09 17:10:34.805  INFO 8712 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-09 17:10:34.814 ERROR 8712 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:17) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
```

my result is they must find embedded tomcat, and it is not option.
this is TomcatWebServer.class

```
   /**
     * Create a new {@link TomcatWebServer} instance.
     * @param tomcat the underlying Tomcat server
     */
    public TomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
        this(tomcat, true);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new {@link TomcatWebServer} instance.
     * @param tomcat the underlying Tomcat server
     * @param autoStart if the server should be started
     */
    public TomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat, boolean autoStart) {
        Assert.notNull(tomcat, "Tomcat Server must not be null");
        this.tomcat = tomcat;
        this.autoStart = autoStart;
        initialize();
    }
```

in IDE tool, we can't use eclipse tomcat? :( it is so sad..

Comment: How are you running your application, and do you have any errors ?

Comment: Springboot by default runs on tomcat server so can you please remove the tomcat dependency and run your application once again.

Comment: can you please share error? i would be happy to answer if you could share what exactly error you are facing

Comment: @Arnaud No, there was no errors. and also no start log in console.

Comment: @GauravRai1512  i will. thanks!

Comment: @ Girdhar Singh Rathore there is no errors. i want to see start log with eclipse tomcat.

Comment: @KJ HEY plese let me know if it’s solve your query. Thanks

Comment: The tomcat server will never look for a main method or class containing one. It will use the web.xml to determine how to deploy.

Comment: @Gerben Jongerius i was thinking spring boot has skill that tomcat can find spring boot application Class..

Comment: Look into this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot has a built in Tomcat, it is run as a Java executable.

Simply right click on the PlusFApplication class and :

```
Run As -> Spring Boot App
```

Or

```
Run As -> Java Application
```

Your class should look like this, Spring Boot will do the rest:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PlusFApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlusFApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

If you're having trouble import a [hello world example](https://github.com/gregclinker/boot-example) and get that working first.

Comment: I don't have such option `Run -> Spring Boot App`, How can it be added?

Comment: @user7294900 your project is not set up correctly, easiest thing is to re-import the source code as a maven project. Exit eclipse, make sure you blow away all the old eclipse folders and files (.project, ,classpath, .settings) before importing again.

Comment: Run As -> Spring Boot App is only available with Spring Tools (STS).

Comment: @PhilippeCloutier it's just a java app running a main class, that's the simplicity, any eclipse will have "Run As", STS has a slightly different menu name.